# How to use live tiles with Qt 5.7 in Windows 10?

Tags: qt, windows-10, live-tile

I was wondering if there was any way to implement Windows Live Tiles feature in a Qt 5.7 application (updating them from the app). I have looked at the documentation, but there isn't seem to be any API for what I want.